How to understand implicitly declared in the right way?
As per the document, which says that the constructor, deconstructor and asignment operator of std::array are implicitly declared. How to understand that?
I fully understand default declared functions(say, default constructor and etc), user provided functions.
What're implicitly declared functions?
As per the tutorial, which says:

The popular type std::array (17.1 -- Introduction to std::array) is also an aggregate.

The cpprefrence clearly states class types which belong to aggregate should have no user-provided, inherited, or explicit constructors. Therefore, it seems that implicitly declared constructor meets the aforementioned requirement.

Looking at your recent questions I would recommend a good c++ book as these things are explained in many beginner c++ books.

How to understand that?.." Ctors that are implicitly declared by the compiler.

@user12002570 Thank you for the reply. I just find the statement below. The default constructor , copy constructor and copy assignment operator and destructor
are special member functions. The implementation will implicitly declare these member functions for a class type when the program does not explicitly declare them.  For the std::array, the default constructor is implicitly defined by the compiler other than the library provider. Therefore, there is no user-provided, inherited, or explicit constructors for the std::array. So std::array belongs to aggregate.

Basically say we have struct C{int a;}; then it's default ctor is implicitly-declared. See the answer below that has references to the standard.

@user12002570 Though, I have learnt the implementation will implicitly declare these member functions for a class type when the program does not explicitly declare them years ago. But i really confused with the implicitly declared mark at that time. Thank you for your advice. I will go out my way to learn the suggested book of original edition.

Yeah, C++ is complex enough that any simple seeming term/concept can be hard to understand. But the term "implicitly declared" is not one such term. When I started learning c++, I used a book named "C++ primer by Lippman" and it explained this in simple way. Then I checked the standard, and it confirmed what the book said. You're welcome.

@user12002570 I see. Thanks a lot for teaching me so much.


What're implicitly declared functions?

These are functions that fall under the category of defaulted functions and implementations shall provide implicit definitions for them. This can be seen from dcl.fct.default#5:

Explicitly-defaulted functions and implicitly-declared functions are collectively called defaulted functions, and the implementation shall provide implicit definitions for them ([class.ctor], [class.dtor], [class.copy.ctor], [class.copy.assign]) as described below, including possibly defining them as deleted.

From special:

An implicitly-declared special member function is declared at the closing } of the class-specifier.
Programs shall not define implicitly-declared special member functions.

(emphasis mine)
So std::array relies on the implicitly declared functions as can be seen from array.cons which says

The conditions for an aggregate shall be met.
Class array relies on the implicitly-declared special member functions ([class.default.ctor], [class.dtor], [class.copy.ctor]) to conform to the container requirements table in [container.requirements].


Since std::array comes from the library, it seems immaterial how something is declared.  If a certain function were explicitly declared std::array, could the program tell the difference between that and implicitly?

@Kaz That(explicitly defining/declaring) would usually make the class non-aggregate. And std::array needs to be an aggregate.

@Kaz if std::array were not an aggregate, it wouldn't be a good replacement for raw arrays; because it would require none-trivial elements to be move/copy constructible and direct initialization of elements via list initialization would become impossible.

My point is that if we are successfuly using some identifier like std::array in a language which requires everything to be declared before it is used, and a declaration of std::array doesn't appear anywhere in our program, then it is implicitly declared. If something is implicitly declared as a whole, every aspect of it is implicitly declared.
